# Intuitive understanding of some important exponential functions

Tags: circles, fourier-transform, euler-mascheroni-constant

After watching these 2 brilliant YouTube Videos--

1) [Euler's formula with introductory group theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ)

2) [But what is the Fourier Transform? A visual introduction.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY&t=776s)

I am facing some difficulty in understanding some of these exponential functions intuitively---

[image]

Comment: Form 1 is form 2 with t = 1. In form 2, as t goes from 0 to 1, $e^{2\pi it}$ rotates around the unit circle anticlockwise. Putting f in (0<f<1) slows that rotation, f in (f>1)  speeds the rotation and f negative rotates clockwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did not watch the videos.

The ideas you are describing are from complex numbers and their geometry. For an introduction I recommend working through the early chapters in one of the many [free complex analysis books available online](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/complex.html).

One of things you learn early on about values in the complex plane is that they can be represented in rectangular form by an expression like $z = x + i y$ where $x$ and $y$ are simply the familiar [rectangular coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). It turns out these numbers can also be represented by the expression $$z = r e^{i\theta}$$ where $\theta$ is an angle (in radians) and $r$ is a magnitude. When $r = 1$ the expression $z = e^{i\theta}$ gives points on the unit circle corresponding to the angle $theta$, and so the function $$f(t) = e^{it}$$ traces out a unit circle as $t$ varies from, say, $0$ to $2\pi.$

So now your question. Consider the equation $g(t) = 2\pi t$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1.$ You'll see that it gives you, in a linear fashion (you graphed it, right?), all values from $0$ to $2\pi.$ Therefore if we look at the function $$f(t) = e^{g(t)} = e^{2 \pi t}$$ we see that it traces out the unit circle as $t$ varies from $0$ to $1.$

Now suppose we look at yet another function $h(t) = g(t) * k$ (I'm using $k$ rather than $f$ to avoid confusion) where $k$ is a real number greater than $0$ but less than $1.$ What happens to the values as we increase $t$ from $0$? You should see that now in order that $h(t) = 2 \pi,$ we must have $2\pi = g(t) * k = 2 \pi t k$ so that, solving for $t$ we get $$t = \frac{1}{k}.$$ Since $0 < k < 1$ we know that $t > 1.$ Thus we now have a function that varies from $0$ to $2\pi$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1/k$ (rather than $1$). OK, now putting this again an exponential function, we obtain $$F(t) = e^{h(t)} = e^{2\pi kt}$$ which will trace out a unit circle as we put in values from $0$ to $1/k$. Since $1/k > 1$ we have that $F$ traces the unit circle more slowly than $f$ did!

Now what if the value $k$ were greater than $1$? Try it out!

Comment: That was a really good explanation,thank you